# Local Server - Mysql takes too long to fetch data from large table (800k rows, 26gb)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server

I was using a file system before, and 1 file containing about 500,000 json_encoded items, taking 8-12gb space. It took me 20s-1min max to fetch this file and decode it.

I decided to use MYSQL and add all the files data to a db_table. It contains 6 string elements and 1 longtext where i save a large json-encoded string.

```
$table->increments('id');
            
$table->string('string1');
$table->string('string2');
$table->string('string3');
$table->string('string4');
$table->string('string5');

            
$table->longtext('json_encoded_array_string')->nullable;
```

However when i try to fetch 800k elements from the table, it is taking way too long.
I don't think my setup is a bottleneck.

SETUP (Local Server):

```
Ubuntu 22
Mysql (Latest)
PHP 8.2

i7-13900k
64gb DDR5
1TB 980 Pro
```

Eventually i want to fetch between 500k-1M rows from the table by date, or ids. For now i'm just testing the time it takes to fetch the whole data currently in the table. ~800,000 rows, 26gb. (this will be 5x larger in the future)

This (takes 284s to get the data):

```
$data = DB::table("data_minute")->where('symbol', $defaultx)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take(100);
```

This (keeps loading >10min):

```
$data = DB::table("data_minute")->where('symbol', $defaultx)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take(1000000);
```

Comment: If the data being retrieved would be relatively constant and unchanging, then consider loading the data into some kind of cache (e.g. Redis), and then reading from that cache.  This should be substantially faster than running a SELECT against MySQL.

Comment: You will need some of cache system but what happens for now if you index the `symbol` column?

Comment: The way you've written your Laravel query means you are using the Collection `take()` method, not the Query Builder method.  That means you're retreiving the entire data set and then discarding most of it, which is massively inefficient.  I think you probably want [`limit()`, not `take()`, anyway](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#skip-take).

Comment: All the usual MySQL and Laravel optimisation recommendations apply so there is plenty to search for here on SO and investigate.  Is there a reason you're using a `longtext` column type instead of [JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-json)?  Is `symbol` indexed?  Stepping back, do you really need to retrieve 800k records at once?  Can you get away with individual pages of smaller sets of records?  How often do you have to make this/these queries?